# React Native - Twilio chat conversation does not receive messages via registered 'messageAdded' listener

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, twilio-conversations

I am currently trying to migrate a mobile react-native application (working with expo) from twilio-chat to twilio-conversations. Already did it with the browser based agent-application which works fine.

The react-native app is able to send messages, which appear in the browser based app, but not in the message list of the mobile app itself. Also my "messageAdded" listener never gets called.

Here is the hook I wrote to handle the interaction with the conversation client (version 2.1.0):

```js
// useTwilioConversation.tsx

import { Client, Conversation, Message } from '@twilio/conversations';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { ConversationType, Session } from '../interfaces/Session';
import useConversationToken from './useConversationToken';
import { useSocket } from './useSocket';

interface ChatOptions {
  session: Session;
}

const useTwilioConversation = (options: ChatOptions) => {
  const [chatReady, setChatReady] = useState(false);
  const [chatConversation, setChatConversation] = useState<Conversation>();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [newMessageAvailable, setNewMessageAvailable] = useState<boolean>(
    false
  );

 useConversationToken({
    session: options.session,
    type: ConversationType.CHAT,
    callback: async (data) => {
      await createClient(data.token);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (chatConversation) {
        chatConversation.removeAllListeners();
        chatConversation.leave();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  // socket context for handling other application communication
  const socket = useSocket();

  const onMessageAdded = (message: Message) => {

    // never gets called
    console.log(
      '-------------------------------------------------------------->NEW MESSAGE: ',
      message
    );
    setMessages((prevMessages) => {
      return [...prevMessages, message];
    });
    setNewMessageAvailable(true);
  };

  const registerListeners = (chatConversation: Conversation) => {
    chatConversation.on('messageAdded', onMessageAdded);
 
    console.log(chatConversation.listenerCount('messageAdded')); // returns '2'
  };

  const onChatConnected = () => {
    socket.emit('deviceConnect', { sessionId: options.session.id });
  };

  const createClient = async (token: string) => {

    const client = await new Client(token, { logLevel: 'debug' });

// works fine
    client.on('stateChanged', (state) => {
      if (state === 'initialized') {
        onInit(client);
      }
    });
    client.on('messageAdded', onMessageAdded);
  };

  const onInit = async (client: Client) => {
    const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(
      options.session.room
    );

    if (conversation) {
     
      if (conversation.status !== 'joined') {
        client.on('conversationJoined', () => {
          registerListeners(conversation);
        });
        await conversation.join();
      } else {
        registerListeners(conversation);
      }
      if (options.session.description !== '')
        await conversation.sendMessage(options.session.description);

      const messages = await conversation.getMessages();
      setMessages(messages.items);
      onChatConnected();
      setChatConversation(conversation);
      setChatReady(true);
    }
  };

 

  const submitMessage = (message: string) => {
    chatConversation?.sendMessage(message);
  };

 
  const readMessages = () => {
    setNewMessageAvailable(false);
  };

  return {
    messages,
    submitMessage,
    chatReady,
    newMessageAvailable,
    readMessages,
  } as const;
};

export default useTwilioConversation;
```

EDIT: Added UseConversationToken.tsx for clarity

```js
// useConversationToken.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { ConversationType, Session } from '../interfaces/Session';
import { useSocket } from './useSocket';

interface ConversationOptions {
  type: ConversationType;
  session: Session;
  callback?: (data: ConversationReadyData) => void;
  timeout?: number;
}

interface ConversationReadyData {
  sessionId: string;
  type: ConversationType;
  token: string;
}

const useConversationToken = (options: ConversationOptions) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const socket = useSocket();

  useEffect(() => {
    const message = `${options.type}ConversationReady`;
    if (socket) {
      socket.on(message, (data: ConversationReadyData) => {
        if (data.sessionId === options.session.id) {
          if (options.timeout && options.timeout > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setToken(data.token);
              if (options.callback) options.callback(data);
            }, options.timeout);
          } else {
            setToken(data.token);
            if (options.callback) options.callback(data);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (socket) socket.off(message);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return token;
};

export default useConversationToken;
```

I also tried this code directly in place instead of using it as a hook which makes no difference.

After sending a few messages to the mobile client, I receive an error, that indicates that there was a problem sending log messages to the devlopment environment. "RangeError: Invalid string length"

Twilio debug logs can be found here: [Logs](https://pastebin.com/qkr1VNBQ)

Updated `useTwilioConversation` hook code:

```js
import { Client, Conversation, Message } from '@twilio/conversations';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { ConversationType, Session } from '../interfaces/Session';
import useConversationToken from './useConversationToken';
import { useSocket } from './useSocket';

interface ChatOptions {
  session: Session;
}

const useTwilioConversation = (options: ChatOptions) => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState<Client>();
  const [chatReady, setChatReady] = useState(false);
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState<Conversation>();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [newMessageAvailable, setNewMessageAvailable] = useState<boolean>(
    false
  );

  const token = useConversationToken({
    session: options.session,
    type: ConversationType.CHAT,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (token) {
        const client = new Client(token, { logLevel: 'debug' });
        setClient(client);

        client.on('stateChanged', async (state) => {
          if (state === 'initialized') {
            const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(
              options.session.room
            );
            setConversation(conversation);
          }
        });
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      if (client) {
        client.removeAllListeners();
        client.shutdown();
      }
    };
  }, [token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (client && conversation) {
        const registerListeners = () => {
          conversation.on('messageAdded', onMessageAdded);


// DOES NOT GET CALLED TOO!
          conversation.on('participantLeft', () => {
            console.log('PARTICIPANT LEFT')
            );
          });
        };
        if (conversation.status !== 'joined') {
          client.on('conversationJoined', () => {
            registerListeners();
          });
          await conversation.join();
        } else {
          registerListeners();
        }
        if (options.session.description !== '')
          await conversation.sendMessage(options.session.description);

        const messages = await conversation.getMessages();
        setMessages(messages.items);
        onChatConnected();
        setChatReady(true);
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      if (conversation) {
        conversation.removeAllListeners();
        conversation.leave();
      }
    };
  }, [conversation]);

  // socket context for handling other application communication
  const socket = useSocket();

  const onMessageAdded = (message: Message) => {
    // never gets called
    console.log(
      '-------------------------------------------------------------->NEW MESSAGE: ',
      message
    );
    setMessages((prevMessages) => {
      return [...prevMessages, message];
    });
    setNewMessageAvailable(true);
  };

  const onChatConnected = () => {
    socket.emit('deviceConnect', { sessionId: options.session.id });
  };

  const submitMessage = (message: string) => {
    conversation?.sendMessage(message);
  };

  const readMessages = () => {
    setNewMessageAvailable(false);
  };

  return {
    messages,
    submitMessage,
    chatReady,
    newMessageAvailable,
    readMessages,
  } as const;
};

export default useTwilioConversation;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what could be going wrong here. I do wonder whether a lot of this code should live within a `useEffect` hook though? I notice that you use a `useEffect` to clear up the conversation, but really you should do all your connection to the Conversations service within a `useEffect` and return a function that cleans that up. Also, you can't `await` a constructor function, because they return an instance of the class, not a promise, so `await new Client(...)` is meaningless.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the client is created in the `useConversationToken` hook callback, which gets executed inside an `useEffect`. Should be working fine. Updated the question with more code

Comment: But the creation of the chat client and subsequent need to destroy it is its own set of side effects. I've played around with your code a bit and to me it seems like you actually need a new `useConversation` hook that takes a client and room name and handles setting up and destroying a conversation outside of this hook which sets up and destroys the client. Though I still don't know why you wouldn't be receiving messageAdded events.

Comment: Followed your advice, but besides more readable code(thanks for that) it didn't change much. I tried to launch the app via an Android Emulator and noticed, that the App crashes a few seconds after the first messages are sent via conversations. Updated the code for the hook.

Comment: This is the last twilio debug log before everything crashes: 

```2022-04-08T17:31:25.954Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147{"id":"TM228ca98dc9e747d293652a22ac35fea9","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}
2022-04-08T17:31:37.735Z Twilsock D: message received:  notification```



React native crashes silently

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with React Native, more React. I am surprised that this would work fine in React and not React Native. This might be something worth raising with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) so that the product team can see what is going on too.

Comment: Exchanging with the support. Will update the question if a solution is found.

Comment: There is no version information regarding which `@twilio/conversations` package you are using.

Comment: `await new Client(` why await a non-Promise?

Comment: yeah, this was already mentioned by philnash and fixed in the updated code. residue of the old twilio/chat sdk. The package version is 2.1.0.

Comment: These lines in your `useEffect()` look suspect to me: `chatConversation.removeAllListeners()` and `chatConversation.leave()` Try removing those and see if you get your messages.

Comment: @stanlemon this is the clean up function of the useEffect, which is only called on the unmounting of the component.